# Helm update and revert on EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm

I'm currently exploring the process of updating Helm from version 3.5.2 to 3.12.3 and would appreciate any insights on reverting back to the previous version if needed.

If I upgrade to Helm 3.12.3 and encounter issues, what are the recommended steps to revert back to Helm 3.5.2 safely? Are there any common pitfalls or considerations I should be aware of?
How might such a rollback affect ongoing deployments or releases managed by Helm? Any strategies to minimize disruption would be highly beneficial.

Your expertise and advice will be instrumental in helping us maintain a stable and efficient deployment process. Looking forward to your valuable suggestions and thank you in advance for your time and assistance!